# Showing $\mathcal{A}^*$ is Well-Quasi-Ordered

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

I was told that the problem below is supposed to prove that $\mathcal{A}^*$ (defined below in "Attempted Solution") is well-quasi-ordered. Two problems come to my mind:

1. How is this problem proving that $\mathcal{A}^*$ is well-quasi-ordered iff the ordered set $A$ is well-quasi-ordered?
2. I have attempted to solve this problem but have not shown (or at least I see it) anything about well-quasi-orderedness.

So what I seek is verification of my solution, a possible answer to #$1$, and how to incorporate well-quasi-orderedness into my solution (or tell me that it is good as is).

**Note:** for the diagrams, refer here: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/56d8455a4bec82fa66fccf12/output/output.pdf?cache_bust=1457321811728&compileGroup=standard&build=1534f260ea2

**Problem**

Show that for any set map $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathcal{A}^*$ there is a morphism (i.e. order preserving map) $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ (in fact $g : 2\to\mathbb{N}$ is enough) such that $fg : \mathbb{N}\to \mathcal{A}^*$ is a morphism.

**Attempted Solution**

(We let Solution $1$ define the preliminaries) Let there be a $\textbf{PrO}$-shaped diagram for the (free functor) $F:\textbf{PrO}\to\textbf{ProM}$. Given the natural number object $\mathbb{N}_\textbf{ProM}\in\text{Obj}(\textbf{ProM})$, the indexing natural and natural number objects $\mathbb{N}_j,\mathbb{N}_\textbf{PrO}\in\text{Obj}(\textbf{PrO})$, we define the cone over $F$ to be the natural transformation $\gamma:\Delta_{\mathbb{N}_{\textbf{PrO}}}\to F$ where $\Delta_{\mathbb{N}_{\textbf{PrO}}}:\textbf{PrO}\to\textbf{ProM}$ is defined by sending the family of indexing natural number objects $\mathbb{N}_j$ to $\mathbb{N}_{\textbf{PrO}}$ and all morphisms of $\mathbb{N}_j$ to $\text{id}_{\mathbb{N}_{\textbf{PrO}}}$. This amounts to giving for the family of indexing natural numbers $\mathbb{N}_j$ of $\textbf{PrO}$, a morphism $\Delta_{\mathbb{N}_{\textbf{PrO}}}(\mathbb{N}_j)=\mathbb{N}_{\textbf{PrO}}\to F(\mathbb{N}_j)=\mathcal{A}^*_j$ such that whenever $h:\mathbb{N}_j\to\mathbb{N}_{j'}$ is a morphism of $\textbf{PrO}$, the diagram

[diagram $1$]

From this, we want to take the limit of the functor $\textbf{PrO}\to\textbf{ProM}$. So the limit of $F$ is a universal cone $(\mathbb{N}_\textbf{ProM},Q_j)$ such that for every cone $(\mathbb{N}_\textbf{PrO},f_j)$ of $F$, there is a unique morphism with respect to $g$ from the problem $F[g]:\mathbb{N}_\textbf{PrO}\to\mathbb{N}_\textbf{ProM}$ such that $Q_j=F[g]\circ f_j$ where the following diagram commutes.

[diagram $2$]

$Q_j=F[g]\circ f_j$ shows that $$[\mathbb{N}_\textbf{ProM}\to^{Q_j}F(\mathbb{N}_j)=\mathcal{A}^*_j]=(\mathbb{N}_\textbf{PrO}\to^{f[g]}\mathbb{N}_\textbf{ProM})\circ(\mathbb{N}_\textbf{PrO}\to^{f_j}\mathcal{A}^*_j).$$ Therefore concluding my solution.

**Comment**

1. I have not gotten how to incorporate showing that $\mathcal{A}^*$ is well-quasi-ordered in this answer and I am sure you would be able to help me with that.
2. I am not sure how the limit will work with $g:2\to\mathbb{N}$. I tried to make $2$ the limit but to me it seemed sort of weird. I also made $\mathbb{N}$ the limit but that also seemed weird.

Comment: You have a wqo $\preceq$ on $A$. Can you explain *without* the category-theoretic terminology how that is extended to a preorder $\sqsubseteq$ on $A^*$? At any rate, the statement of the problem seems to be exactly the statement that $A^*$ is wqo by whatever extension you’re using: for each sequence $f$ of words there are $i,j\in\Bbb N$ such that $i<j$ and $f(i)\sqsubseteq f(j)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It is extended by the subword order: given the preorder $\mathcal{A}=(A,\leqslant_A)$, the *subword order* $\preccurlyeq_{A^*}$ on the set of all strings $A^*$ over $A$ is defined such that for $u_1\cdots u_m,v_1\cdots v_n\in A^*$, $u_1 \cdots u_m\preccurlyeq_{A^*}v_1\cdots v_n$ if and only if there exists $m$ indexes $j_1,\cdots,j_m$ with $1\leq j_1<\cdots<j_m\leq n$ such that for all $i$, $u_i\leqslant_Av_{j_i}$. Source: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/569c7839de5631c80dafbfad/output/output.pdf?cache_bust=1457324972702&compileGroup=standard&build=1534f564a51

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In the source linked in my previous comment, everything up to Lemma $3.2$ is everything you need to know. After Lemma $3.2$, everything else is being removed.

Comment: Okay; that’s the usual extension. I don’t do category theory and have no hope of following your argument, but I can answer your first question: what you are trying to prove (if you use $\mathbf{2}$ rather than $\Bbb N$ as the domain of $g$) is precisely the definition of the extension being a wqo.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott See I am tasked with proving it categorically... Can you elaborate on using $2$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$ in your answer to my first question?

Comment: I’ll use my notation above. To show that $\sqsubseteq$ is a wqo, you need to show that if $\langle w_0,w_1,\ldots\rangle$ is an infinite sequence of words over the alphabet $A$, then there are indices $i$ and $j$ such that $i<j$ and $w_i\sqsubseteq w_j$. The sequence is essentially the map $f$ in the problem statement; $g:\mathbf{2}\to\Bbb N$ takes $0$ to $i$ and $1$ to $j$, so that $fg$ is the order-preserving map that takes $0$ to $w_i$ and $1$ to $w_j$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Still a little confused. So $0,1\in2$? I think I am just confusing myself.

Comment: From a set-theoretic point of view $2=\{0,1\}$, so that’s the way I’m viewing it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think don't get how this all comes together.

Comment: It was getting a bit long for comments, so I’ve written out an expanded version of the discussion as a partial answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t help with the category theory at all, but I can explain how this is a proof of Higman’s lemma.

Consider the following two problems.

1. You have $f:\Bbb N\to A^*$; that’s simply a sequence $\langle f(0),f(1),\ldots\rangle$ of words over $A$. You want to show that there’s an order-preserving $g:\{0,1\}\to\Bbb N$ such that $fg:\{0,1\}\to A^*$ is order-preserving.
2. Alternatively, To show that $\sqsubseteq$ is a wqo on $A^*$, you must show that if $\langle w_0,w_1,\ldots\rangle$ is a sequence of words over $A$, there are $i,j\in\Bbb N$ such that $i<j$ and $w_i\sqsubseteq w_j$. (This assertion is Higman’s lemma.)

I claim that these are the same thing. Identify the sequence $\langle w_0,w_1,\ldots\rangle$ with $f$: $f(i)=w_i$. Suppose that you can find $i$ and $j$ as in (2). Then define $g:\{0,1\}\to\Bbb N$ by $g(0)=i$ and $g(1)=j$; $g$ is order-preserving, since $i<j$. Moreover,

$$(fg)(0)=f(i)=w_i\sqsubseteq w_j=f(j)=(fg)(1)\;,$$

so $fg$ is order-preserving. Thus, if we can do (2), we can do (1).

Now suppose that we can find $g$ as in (1). Then let $i=g(0)$ and $j=g(1)$, and you can easily check that they satisfy the requirements of (2). Thus, (1) also implies (2), and the two are equivalent.

Comment: Ah now I got it. So no matter what $i$ and $j$ are, $g(0)$ will equal any $i$ and $g(1)$ will equal any $j$ such that $i<j$. Then $fg$ makes $i$ and $j$ the indices of $w$.

Comment: @Julian: Almost: $g(1)$ can’t be just **any** $j>i$, since it has to satisfy $w_i\sqsubseteq w_j$ (equivalently, it has to make $fg$ order-preserving). But it can be any $j>i$ that does that.

Comment: So by "can't be 'any'" you mean like we restrict $I,j\in\mathbb{N}$? Also, why do we have $\{0,1\}$ as the domain of $g$?

Comment: @Julian: I simply meant that it’s not sufficient to require that $j>i$: you also need to require that $w_i\sqsubseteq w_j$. That’s the whole point, in fact. \\ The definition of wqo says that each infinite sequence has a two-element increasing subsequence; taking the domain of $g$ to be $\{0,1\}$ makes $fg$ a two element subsequence of $f$.

Comment: Ah now that clears it up. I understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Julian: You’re welcome.

Comment: I actually have one last question: by "two-element subsequence" you mean $(w_i,w_j)\subset A^*$ such that $w_i\preccurlyeq w_j$?

Comment: @Julian: Any pair $\langle w_i,w_j\rangle$ with $i<j$ would be a two-element subsequence; if in addition $w_i\sqsubseteq w_j$, it’s a two-element *increasing* subsequence.